# Many exit nodes unable to download from file hosting sites

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, exit-relays

My country recently blocked quite a number of popular file hosting sites (e.g. uploaded.net) at the IP level.

Using Tor circumvents this but I'm finding that most (nearly all?) Tor exit nodes are almost always past their free download limit on most of these.

I do try again and again after getting a 'new identity' but the process is laborious and most exit nodes are already past their limits. Is there any way I can work around this issue without subscribing to a 'premium' account on these sites?

Comment: I've also been trying this. Have you managed to find a solution that doesn't involve buying an account anywhere?

Answer (score 4):

Tor is **not meant** for downloading (large) files. This is slowing down the network.

In your case I would suggest you one of the following

- use/buy a VPN in combination with a premium account
- use a service like **rapid8.com** or **premiumize.me** (most valuable when you download frequently from different hosters)

Comment: Okay. I must add that I never download music/videos/other large files through tor. This is actually just for ebooks (mostly ~30Mb), but I see your point. Will check out a VPN package. Thanks.

Comment: On the flip side, using Tor to download files (even if you don't really need the anonymity) does increase the anonymity for others by creating cover traffic that will make deanonymizing attempts by adversaries harder.